# How to use bytebuddy to set annotation @Value in private variable

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, byte-buddy, javaagents

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcQ4o.png)

```html
Class<?> metricTags = new ByteBuddy()
                .subclass(Object.class)
                .name("demo.metrics.MetricTags")
                .annotateType(AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(Component.class).build())
                .annotateType(AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(Data.class).build())
                .defineField("sourceApp", String.class, Visibility.PUBLIC)
                .annotateField(AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(Value.class).define("sourceApp", "dsdw23").build())
                .defineField("sourceServiceNamespace", String.class, Visibility.PRIVATE)
                .defineField("sourceServiceName", String.class, Visibility.PRIVATE)
                .defineField("protocol", String.class, Visibility.PRIVATE).value("http")
                .defineField("appName", String.class, Visibility.PRIVATE)
                .make()
                .load(AgentMain.class.getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
                .getLoaded();
```

report error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface lombok.Value does not define a property named sourceApp

Comment: Can you show you properties file content?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the Value annotation does not define a property of thst name. You can only define properties that are declared by the annotation type.